# Rails 4.2.3 Serialized Model Attribute Not Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

I'm running Rails 4.2.3. I have a model, `Volunteer`, with a serialized attribute, `participated`. After object creation, I can't update the `participated` attribute:

```
> @volunteer = Volunteer.new( participated: {'citizenship' => '', 'daca' => ''} )
 => #<Volunteer id: 1, participated: {'citizenship' => '', 'daca' => ''}>

> @volunteer.participated['citizenship'] = 'test'
 => {'citizenship' => 'test', 'daca' => ''}

> @volunteer
 => #<Volunteer id: 1, participated: {'citizenship' => 'test', 'daca' => ''}>

> @volunteer.changed?
 => true

> @volunteer.save
 => true

> Volunteer.last
 => #<Volunteer id: 1, participated: {'citizenship' => '', 'daca' => ''}>
```

As you can see, the database isn't being updated. I was originally running rails 4.2.0. At that time, `changed?` wasn't even returning `true`--in this scenario, it was returning `false`. After some searching, [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18926) on GitHub led me to suspect that the issue might be a Rails bug. Updating to rails 4.2.3 fixed the problems with `changed?`, but the database still isn't updating.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I've sunk several hours into this so far.

For what its worth:

```
class Volunteer < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :participated
end

class CreateVolunteers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :volunteers do |t|
     t.text :participated
     t.timestamps null: false
   end
  end
end
```